# Create a save data using Django post_save() Signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-signals

Here I want to create a heatmap when a Lead is created, it'll create an example api for the particular API.
This is my lead model and another model for the api, here I want to add a new example api when a new api is been created.

Lead- Signals.py

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Lead
from heatmap.models import HeatMap

@receiver(post_save, sender=Lead)
def create_heatmap_for_lead(sender, created,instance, **kwargs):
    print("signal is sent to heatmap")
    print("-------------------------------")
    # if created:
    #     HeatMap.objects.create(lead=instance)
```

Heatmap - models.py

```py
class HeatMap(ModelMixin):
    heatmap_type = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    followUpDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

You have to change the signal function, You try to get `created` from `kwargs`. created is already defined in the function parameter also same for `instance`. See the code for a better understanding:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Lead)
def create_heatmap_for_lead(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        HeatMap.objects.create(heatmap_type=instance)
```

Comment: @receiver(post_save, sender=Lead)
def create_heatmap(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        HeatMap.objects.create(lead = instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Lead)
def save_heatmap(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.heatmap.save()

Comment: I'm getting error.

Comment: What is the error? @KRISHNANDURANJNROY

Comment: psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "comment" of relation "heatmap_heatmap" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Try this: ```heatmap = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=HEAT_MAP, null=True, blank=True)```

Comment: I've try this, but the requirement is when a lead is created i've to send a post save signal to create heatmap for the lead, I'm able send the signal and its working but i dont understand how to create a heatmap using the lead id. Can we connect mey be it will help

Comment: In the `HeatMap` model which field refers to lead? In your question, there are no such fields that refer to a relation between `HeatMap` and `Lead` models. BTW you can get a lead instance in the signal method in the `instance` parameter. If you want to access `ID` of `Lead` you can simply get it by `instance.id`

Comment: Not Working, showing that the heatmap is not instance of lead.

Comment: I edited my answer. And one thing is that you may make the `status` field nullable, I reckon.